# Integer.parseInt("9999999990");

Tags: java, exception

I am getting NumberFormatException for the String 9999999990 but not when I use 1111111110
when I call Integer.parseInt over that String.
Let me know what is the wrong.

```
String str="9999999990";
  int f = Integer.parseInt("2147483647");// No Exception here
        int x =Integer.parseInt(str);   // Exception is thrown here
```

Comment: Yes because there is a max value to an int

Comment: [Integer.MAX_VALUE](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#MAX_VALUE)

Comment: Overview of Java Datatypes: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html

Answer (score 9):

An `int` can only have a maximum value of 2147483647, so if you try to parse a number larger than that you'll get an exception (since it's not a valid `int`.)

`Long.parseLong()` will handle larger numbers, though bear in mind it still has an upper limit (2^63-1). If you really need a type without an upper limit, you'll have to use [`BigInteger`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html) (which has a constructor that takes a string.)

(You can find more information on all the primitive data types and their maximum values [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html).)

Comment: Without looking it up I'll go out on a limb here and say that the max value of a long is 2^63-1 since it's signed.

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson Doh. Mistype, sorry.

Answer (score 8):

[`Integer.parseInt`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt-java.lang.String-) will throw an exception when what it's parsing can't be represented as an `int`.  The first example is almost 10 billion, which is larger than the largest possible `int`, which is a little over 2 billion.

`Integer.parseInt(String)` delegates to [`Integer.parseInt(String, 10)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt-java.lang.String-int-), the version that takes a radix, and those Javadocs state:

> An exception of type NumberFormatException is thrown if any of the following situations occurs:
>
> - The first argument is null or is a string of length zero.
> - The radix is either smaller than Character.MIN_RADIX or larger than Character.MAX_RADIX.
> - Any character of the string is not a digit of the specified radix, except that the first character may be a minus sign '-' ('\u002D') or plus sign '+' ('\u002B') provided that the string is longer than length 1.
> - The value represented by the string is **not a value of type int**.

(emphasis mine)

If you need it parsed, you can use [`Long.parseLong`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Long.html#parseLong-java.lang.String-), which will handle larger numbers.

Comment: Or hey, if the numbers are too large for a long, `new BigInteger(hugeHonkingNumberString)`